# How to express curvature of a level set in terms of derivatives of a function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Suppose I have a smooth function $u:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$.
Assume that its gradient doesn't vanish (near any point where we investigate it).
Is there a list of different (intrinsic and extrinsic) curvature quantities of level sets of $u$ in terms of derivatives of $u$?
I have been unable to find such a list.

The level set is a Riemannian manifold and its curvature can be described by various curvature tensors.
It is also a submanifold of the ambient $\mathbb R^n$ and the second fundamental form describes its curvature as a submanifold.
These are what I refer to as intrinsic and extrinsic curvature quantities.

Here are two examples of questions that the list should answer.
*I am looking for a resource that would contain the answer to these two questions and many others, not just the answer to these two. These example questions give a criterion for what I am looking for, that's all. This question is a reference request.*

- If $n=3$, what is the Gaussian curvature of $u^{-1}(u(0))$ at $0$ in terms of derivatives of $u$?
- How to express the mean curvature of the level set in terms of derivatives of $u$ in any dimension?

Comment: Have you looked through do Carmo?

Comment: @Neal, I haven't. Based on a quick glance it seems like a probable source, so I will take a look. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

For the first, you might want to look at a tech report I wrote several years back:

http://cs.brown.edu/people/jhughes/papers/Hughes-DGO-2003/paper.pdf

For the second, there's a quite general paper (of which why tech report is a distillation in the 3D case, with a correction):

Peter Dombrowski. Krümmungsgrößen gleichungsdefinierter untermannigfaltigkeiten riemmannscher mannigfaltigkeiten. Mathematische Nachrichten, 38(3/4):133–180, 1968.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at the report when I have the time. I actually already knew the answer to the second question (the 1-Laplacian of $u$), but I included it as an example because it is in the spirit of things that I would like to see. (I tried to improve the formatting of the German title. I hope I got it right.)

Comment: @John Hughes, the link you posted is broken nowadays.

Comment: Fixed! (They changed my username a few months back, darn it!)